# Javascript if condition fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
name =  u'pycon'
name_list = u'acxack', u'pycon', u'A_ForA', u'retweetstats',
            u'Bsdsad', u'dcxcxzc', u'ss'
```

I have to write if `name in name_list` return `true else false`. I have written:

```
var x;

function is_following(name_list, name) {
    for(var f=0; f<name_list.length; f++)  {
            if("u'"+name+"'" == name_lis[f]) {
            x= true;

        }
    }
    return x
```

But everytime it returns false. But It should be returning true, because the required condition is like:

```
If name in name_list:
       return true 
else:
       return false
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy of the code you're using? Your 'if' statement has a typo in it: `if("u'"+name+"'" == name_lis[f])` should be `if("u'"+name+"'" == name_list[f])`. I would start there and see how far you get.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, I'd do it this way:

```
var name_list = {
    "u'acxack'": true,
    "u'pycon'": true,
    "u'A_ForA'": true,
    "u'retweetstats'": true,
    "u'Bsdsad'": true,
    "u'dcxcxzc'": true,
    "u'ss'": true
}

function is_following(list, name) {
    return(list[name] ? true: false);

}

console.log(is_following( name_list, "u'pycon'"));   // true
```

If you put the values in an object like this, you can just look them up directly and see if they are there or not kind of like a hash table.

Comment: Why not use `indexOf` on an array?

Comment: indexOf is not universally supported (IE6-IE8 are the culprits) so you'd have to put in a shim for it.  If you already have the shim installed, then it works fine.  If the only purpose of the data is for lookup, then I'm assuming an object is always faster since it's some type of optimized hashtable internally.

Answer (score 1):

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehv8u/3/)

```
var name =  "u'pycon'";
    name_list = ["u'acxack'", "u'pycon'", "u'A_ForA'", "u'retweetstats'",
               "u'Bsdsad'", "u'dcxcxzc'", "u'ss'"];

function is_following(name_list, name) {
    var x;
    for (var f = 0; f < name_list.length; f++) {
        if (name == name_list[f]) {
            x = true;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

alert(is_following(name_list, name));
```

It mostly works, I had to fix a type `name_lis` and fix the data to be real JS data.

Comment: If the name is not found, x will never be set and you will be returning `undefined` rather than `false`.  I would suggest that rather than setting `x = true`, you should just `return(true);` when found and then at the end of the function just `return(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bad line:

```
  if("u'"+name+"'" == name_list[f]) {
```

You are prepending u' to name, but name already starts with u', so you are checking for u'u'pycon